# PHP Form to Database

Tags: php, mysql, database, forms

Hi I am trying to get a form to post to a database i can connect and the database and table are set up. but rather than post the contents of the fields in it posts the text firstname and secondname in to the columns.

below is my code:

```
mysql_select_db("company", $conn);

    $sqlCmd = sprintf("INSERT INTO names (firstname, secondname) VALUES ('%firstname','%secondname')", 
        mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["firstname"]),
        mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["secondname"]));

    //echo $sqlCmd;
    //die();    

    mysql_query($sqlCmd);

    mysql_close($conn);
}

?>



    <form method="post">
<input type="text" id="firstname" name="firstname"/>
<input type="text" id="secondname" name="secondname"/>
    <input name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
```

I need it to post the values from the fields. i am new to php and this is my first project, i would love some help.

just to add this is what i have managed after following a tutorial.

Thanks

Ryan

Comment: you forgot to `mysql_connect`

Comment: In the sptintf function replace %firstname and %secondanem with %s

Comment: I have already got this and it works

Comment: changing it also did not work *it now does work it kept changing it when i published it. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change your sprintf call to:

```
$sqlCmd = sprintf("INSERT INTO names (firstname, secondname) VALUES ('%s','%s')", 
    mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["firstname"]),
    mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["secondname"]));
```

Also consider using the newer mysqli function: http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.mysqli.php

HTH;
Pacific

Answer (score 1):

Do not use php's mysql_ methods any more.

It is outdated:
https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation

Use mysqli_ or pdo instead

In your code you forgot the `mysql_connect()` anyways ;)